# How to specify an iface to map container port on AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, boto

I have an EC2 instance with eth0 and eth1 interfaces that runs 2 docker containers. Now I want to map port 5000 of container0 to port 5000 on host to eth0 and port 5000 from container1 to eth1. Is it possible w/o using 3d-party tools like pipework or weave?